# Почему не работает remove class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Почему не работает remove class?

```js
$('.pagination a').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('a').removeClass('pagination-active');
    $(this).addClass('pagination-active');
});
```

```css
.pagination .pagination-active {
    color: #E18848;
}
.pagination a {
    color: black;
}

.pagination a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example" class="bar-btn">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true"><i
                        class="fas fa-chevron-left left-arrow"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item "><a class="page-link pagination-active" href="#">1</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right right-arrow"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что они не `siblings` (элементы первого уровня под одним родителем).

```
$(this).closest('ul').children('li').children('a').removeClass('pagination-active');
```

или, если там не будет вложенных списков:

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('li a').removeClass('pagination-active');
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо благодарю через 10 минут приму ответ